# Suspended to cool down

Tags: discussion, support

Logged in,

Got a bunch of notifications.

Click on the last one.

Read the answer.

Try to upvote it.

"Suspended users can't vote"

Goes on worldbuilding meta, can't even post...

Searches for support, can't find it.

So what's about that?  Have I been using too much stackedchange? Or is it again the mods thinking I'm voting myself just because my questions get more than the average 3 upvotes per question?

-Drien

Comment: At the bottom of every page you'll find a "Contact" link that includes, among other options, the request to appeal a suspension. The Mods will not talk about your suspension publicly and no one else has an answer for you since we don't and can't know what triggered the suspension. If you don't wish to wait out the suspension (which, based on experience, always has a good reason), then your proper next step is to use that Contact link.

Answer (score 4):

It is [SO policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293213/why-we-dont-keep-public-records-of-suspensions/293389) to not talk publicly about suspensions This is done to protect suspended individuals from gossip and undue public scrutiny. The expectation is that after a suspension is over a user should be able to return to the site and participate in it as if the suspension never happened. No public records of suspensions is kept and as a rule, Mods do not talk about suspensions. All that anyone who isn't a mod can see is that your account is temporarily suspended for 7 days, for you to cool down. I suspect that unless you deliberately turn this private issue into a public one that's all you're going to find out from this post.

In the future I'd STRONGLY suggest against creating a second account, circumventing the suspension, to discuss it on meta. It reflects poorly on your willingness to abide by site policy. Instead, take the time to cool down, reflect on the information they've given you privately about the suspension, and if you have specific questions, you can request clarification privately from the mods, after your suspension is over.

Comment: I think the issue was this : "reflect on the information they've given you privately about the suspension". If you didn't receive properly the information, it's harder to reflect x). This is why from the content I'm not against asking where to find it (though the slightly dis-content-ed form could look happier :/).